# Generating a Lexer and Parser in Antlrworks Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

I'm trying to learn to use Antlr and have chosen to continue using  Netbeans IDE. I am using version 8.01 because of a dependencies problem in 02.

I've got it working and can look at the tree and stuff.

The question is rather simple. How do I generate the Lexer and Parser?

During the couple of years I've been programming I've never really had to use the comand line in windows, and all the info I could find is just code snippets which I can't uderstand.

I would really appreciate a detailed answer on this topic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should rather read the Antlr book or an introductory tutorial, this is a very basic question.

Comment: If you have the plugin installed, just select the file, then Run->GenerateRecognizer